# Possible to retry once based on a condition?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a method that works, looks essentially like this:

```
public IObservable<List<Stuff>> GetGoodStuff()
{
    return Observable.FromAsync(GetAccessTokenAsync)
        .SelectMany(accessToken =>
        {
            return httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        })
        .SelectMany(response => 
        { 
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 
            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
        })
        .Select(json => 
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stuff>>(json);
        });
}
```

The "GetAccessTokenAsync" returns a cached access token for the api, or, the first time will go fetch a token. The rest of it is pretty standard in terms of httpclient and Rx things.

Here's the thing: I'd like to catch a 401 error, renew the access token, and then retry the whole thing. But just once - after that it can throw the exception out to the caller.

In that middle block I can do this:

```
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                InvalidateAccessToken();
                // what now???
            }
```

But then what? Not seeing how a recursive call would work. Somehow wrap the whole thing? Not seeing it yet...

### EDIT 1 - 7Nov2015

Both answers at this date looked good. The more declarative approach seemed to be less of a change and able to hide much of the "plumbing", but I couldn't quite get it to work in all scenarios.

So based on @Timothy Shields recommendations I came up with this which reads nice and hides the plumbing well (and oh yeah it works :-)

```
/// <summary>
/// Makes an httpclient request using the access token. If Unauthorized is received the access
/// token will be reacquired and the request will be retried once.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The json result from a successful request.</returns>
async Task<string> MakeRequestWithAccessToken(string requestUri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    const int RetryCount = 1;

    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    for (int i = 0; i <= RetryCount; i++)
    {
        var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenAsync();

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        var client = new RemoteService(ApiUrl).NewClient();

        response = await client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        if (i < RetryCount && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            InvalidateAccessToken();
            continue;
        }

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }

    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}

public IObservable<List<Stuff>> GetGoodStuff(int maxCount)
{
    return Observable.FromAsync(async cancellationToken =>
    {
        var requestUri = string.Format("mypath.json?count={0}", maxCount);
        var json = await MakeRequestWithAccessToken(requestUri, cancellationToken);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stuff>>(json);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make use of `async`-`await` to do this:

```
public IObservable<List<Stuff>> GetGoodStuff()
{
    return Observable.FromAsync(async cancellationToken =>
    {
        const int RetryCount = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= RetryCount; i++)
        {
            var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenAsync();
            var request = MakeRequest(accessToken);
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            if (i < RetryCount && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                InvalidateAccessToken();
                continue;
            }
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stuff>>(json);
        }
    });
}
```

This technique allows you to write standard imperative code, exposed as a nice `IObservable<T>`.

Note that I am left guessing exactly how your "retry" will look. It's not clear what you want done after calling `InvalidateAccessToken()`, so I took a guess and invented the `MakeRequest` method. It should be easy for you to adapt this to code that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Nice answer, Timothy. I think this is more readable at first glance than the declarative-style answer. Seeing as how there may be several of these types of client-side requests making calls to corresponding server-side API's I was hoping to find something that could hide the plumbing a bit more though. The looping and temp/locals take away from the main purpose of the method (wrapping a server side endpoint). Tradeoffs...

Comment: @DennisWelu You can extract the common Retry behavior into a separate function that you use in the other methods.

Comment: Right on. In the end this worked very well. Thanks for getting me pointed in a good direction!

Answer (score 2):

I've made the assumption that InvalidateAccessToken is also async in the same way that GetAccessTokenAsync is.

The solution will trigger the invalidation and continue by throwing an exception allowing the retry to trigger.  If the request fails a second time the invalidation sequence will just replay the exception which will bubble up to the subscriber.

```
public IObservable<List<Stuff>> GetGoodStuff()
{
    var invalidate = Observable.FromAsync(InvalidateAccessTokenAsync)
                .Select(x => Observable.Throw<string>(new Exception()))
                .Switch()
                .Replay()
                .RefCount();

    return Observable.FromAsync(GetAccessTokenAsync)
        .SelectMany(accessToken =>
        {
            return httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        })
        .SelectMany(response => 
        { 
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                return invalidate;
            }

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 
            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ToObservable(); 
        })
        .Select(json => 
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stuff>>(json);
        })
        .Retry(1);
}
```

Edit: To answer @supertopi questions

The `Select` in the invalidate sequence returns an `IOberservable<IOberservable<string>>`. We're only interested in the inner sequence so I use the `Switch` operator to move onto the inner sequence.

The `Replay` operator returns an `IConnectableObservable<string>` which will replay the values from its source when subscribed to. The `IConnectableObservable<T>` essentially allows us to share the data values and as the values are replayed, `Observable.FromAsync(InvalidateAccessTokenAsync)` will only get called once. Any late subscribers will only see the replayed values which will be the exception. Take a look at the [definition](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#PublishAndConnect) on introintorx for a thorough explanation.

Without the `RefCount` operator I would need to manually call connect on the `IConnectableObservable`. I use `RefCount` to handle the connection for me and convert the sequence back into an `IObservable<string>`. Again more info can be found [here](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#RefCount).

Comment: Nice answer. Can you further explain, why `invalidate` requires `Switch()` , `Replay()` and `RefCount()` combination?

Comment: Shazam. There's a lot of wholesome goodness in that answer! My only question is the Retry(1): won't that end up retrying if EnsureSuccessStatusCode() throws an exception for some other reason too?

Comment: This looks very promising...but I couldn't quite get it to work in all paths.